# How to make an application run in both win xp and win 7-x86?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have an application that runs in any one OS (either win7(x86) or win xp).

My project is designed in Visual studio 2010, I am using .Net 4.0.

Earlier the project's "working directory" in the properties was specified for win 7 but when i build my project it said unable to locate the  working directory(`C:\Program Files(x86)\app`)

I now changed my working to directory as `C:\Program Files\app`. My application acts as a plugin to MS excel 2003. And now i am able to run it.

so how can i make my application run in both win xp and win 7?

I am using WinForms .net 4.0 c#.

```
 private void MyMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyMenuItem.Enabled = false;   
        string installPath;
        string helpFileName;
        string appName;


installPath =   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
        appName = "\\MyApp\\";   



        if (System.IO.File.Exists(installPath + appName+ helpFileName))
        {


System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(new System.Windows.Forms.Control()                              installPath + appName + helpFileName, 
                   System.Windows.Forms.HelpNavigator.TableOfContents);
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration

In System.IO there's a static class called Path with some very nice stuff on

Struggled a bit because I can't see where you are getting helpFileName from...

```
private void MyMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyMenuItem.Enabled = false;   
   String helpFileName = "IDoNotKnow.ext";
   string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),Path.Combine("MyApp",helpfileName));
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
   {
      System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(new System.Windows.Forms.Control(),fileName,System.Windows.Forms.HelpNavigator.TableOfContents);
   }
}
```

One of the things Path.Combine does for you is you don't have to worry about the backslashes. If there's a trailing one on an argument it uses it, if there isn't it pops it in. Hides a lot of mess that, on occasion.

Comment: -should "public string LANG_FOLDER_PATH = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\app\\lang\\"; " i have made this change to work both on xp and win,does this work?

Comment: No reason why not from this persepective. However, don't concatenate paths, have a look at Path.Combine in System.IO

Comment: Addendum to answer added to illustrate the joy that is Path.Combine

Comment: but this do remove the conflict of working in win7?? i also can see some targetplatform set to x86.?

Comment: is this "fileName" can also be the .xml file? actually i have a folder "lang" in SpecialFolder that has lang_de & lang_en.

Comment: eh filename is just somne were to store all the bits to it. And if you are doing it through special folder, there shouldn't be a conflict.